# More efficient way to bind variables with buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 different buttons that when clicked on will increment specific variable by 1. 
Instead of writing 3 different on clicks, is there more efficient way to do this?
I know i can use data attributes to bind button with correct element, but i don't know how to do that with variables.

```js
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x3 = 0;


$('.btn1').on('click', function() {
  x1 += 1;
  $('#panel1').html(x1);
});
$('.btn2').on('click', function() {
  x2 += 1;
  $('#panel2').html(x2);
});
$('.btn3').on('click', function() {
  x3 += 1;
  $('#panel3').html(x3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel3">
  0
</div>
<button class="btn1">#btn1</button>
<button class="btn2">#btn2</button>
<button class="btn3">#btn3</button>
```

Comment: data attributes

Comment: bind onclick to wrapper and use e.target may be?

Comment: This best option depends a lot on how you plan on using the variables, and the structure of your page. It might be worth expanding on what your end goal is so we can give relevant advice.

Comment: As per @epascarello : `$(".btn").click(function() { $(this).data("x", $(this).data("x")+1); });`  or (more confusing, search for the many duplicates) `$(".btn").click(function() { window[$(this).data("varname")]+=1; }); ` with `<button class='btn' data-varname="x1">bn1</button>`

Comment: My end goal is not having hundreds of on clicks if i have hundreds of buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using id's or whatever attribute and arrays:

```
var x = [];
    x[1] = 0;
    x[2] = 0;
    x[3] = 0;


$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var pos = $(this).attr("id");
  x[+pos] += 1;
  $('#panel'+pos).html(x[pos]);
});
```

in HTML:

```
<button class="btn" id="1">#btn1</button>
<button class="btn"  id="2">#btn2</button>
<button class="btn"  id="3">#btn3</button>
```

Comment: Small and simple. Thanks

Comment: @Pleinair You’re welcome

Comment: Don't use `.html()` for strings that don't contain any HTML. Use `.text()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

As always, use a function to abstract over duplicated code.

```
function counter(buttonSelector, outputSelector) {
  var x = 0;
  $(buttonSelector).on('click', function() {
    x += 1;
    $(outputSelector).text(x); // btw, don't use `html`
  });
}
counter('.btn1', '#panel1');
counter('.btn2', '#panel2');
counter('.btn3', '#panel3');
```

You can further remove repetition by putting those calls (or just the function body) in a loop, and/or adjust your selectors appropriately, but for three calls it's not yet worth it.

Comment: @j08691 The question says "*I have 3 different buttons*"

Comment: Right but he also commented "My end goal is not having hundreds of on clicks if i have hundreds of buttons", so I assume that the three is just a representative example for the question.

Comment: @j08691 Ah, I had not read that. Well, if he has hundreths of buttons he hopefully also has an appropriate data structure to iterate over. I already added a sentence in that regard to my answer, but without more details I can't recommend anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Give them the same class and make it one click listener and put a data attr on each button with the variable name and the panel name. something like this, put all the variables in one object so you can access them also if they are global variables you can access them like this window[variableName]

Answer (score 0):

I would either give your buttons a common class, or you could just bind your click event to the button element if you don't have others you need to worry about. Then use the index of the button being clicked to match it to the div you want to change. Essentially a one-liner:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('div').eq($(this).index('button')).html(+$('div').eq($(this).index('button')).text() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel3">
  0
</div>
<button class="btn1">#btn1</button>
<button class="btn2">#btn2</button>
<button class="btn3">#btn3</button>
```

Parts explained:

- `$(this).index('button')` gets the index of the button among the button elements. See [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/).
- `$('div').eq($(this).index('button')).text()` select the div using the index above. See [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- `+` converts the string content of the div to a number. Also could have used `parseInt()`

Comment: 'essentially a one-liner', true, tho I would need the corresponding decryption function as well to understand it :)

Comment: @MatusDubrava I've added some extra info to explain the various parts. Let me know if I left anything out.

Answer (score 0):

Store the count in data attributes instead of a variable.

```js
$('button[data-out]').on('click', function() {  // bind on every button
// $(document).on('click, 'button[data-out]', function() { // or use event delegation with one click event
  var btn = $(this) // reference the element
  var cnt = (btn.data('count') || 0) + 1  // read count or default to zero and increment
  btn.data('count', cnt)  // update the count data attribute
  $(btn.data('out')).text(cnt)  // update your text output
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel3">
  0
</div>
<button class="btn1" data-out="#panel1">#btn1</button>
<button class="btn2" data-out="#panel2">#btn2</button>
<button class="btn3" data-out="#panel3">#btn3</button>
```

Comment: Cleanest solution IMO.

Comment: @Mikey I think it's cleaner to just use the content of the `div` elements instead of duplicating it in attributes. See my answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus than you will have to parse it each time with parseInt/Number() and have to hope that stuff like browser text translators did not muck with the content. Yes it can be done with the text content of the div itself to me, easier to just use a data attribute. Just personal opinions on "what is best"

Comment: @epascarello Not if the only content in the `div` is the number. You only need to convert it to a number, which is done implicitly when `++` is used. See my answer below.

Comment: If you need use results anywhere? You will use selector every place for access to data-attribute?

Comment: It could be mapped to an array, really does not matter.... No clue what OP is doing so hard to giv the "best" answer which is subjective.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array instead of multi variables.
now give all buttons a specific class like btn.
then :

```
var ar=[0,0,0];
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
    var x=$(this).html(); //if text of buttons is #btn1,#btn2 , ....
    var num=parseInt(x.substr(x.length - 1));
    ar[num]++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Store the variables as properties of an object.
- Use a `data-*` attribute on each button to store what variable it is
  supposed to match.
- Bind all buttons to one handler.
- In the handler, check the clicked button's `data-` attribute and
  update the associated Object property as needed.

```js
let variableObject = {
 x1:0,
 x2:0,
 x3:0
}

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  variableObject[this.dataset.key]++;
  $('#panel' + this.dataset.key.charAt(1)).text(variableObject[this.dataset.key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">0</div>
<div id="panel2">0</div>
<div id="panel3">0</div>
<button class="btn" data-key="x1">#btn1</button>
<button class="btn" data-key="x2">#btn2</button>
<button class="btn" data-key="x3">#btn3</button>
```

Having said that, do you really need the variables in the first place? Why can't you just adjust the HTML content directly and anytime you may need that data, simply extract it.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  // Get current value of associated panel
  let current = $("#" + $(this).data("key")).text();
  
  // Set text of associated panel to old value plus one
  $("#" + $(this).data("key")).text(++current);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">0</div>
<div id="panel2">0</div>
<div id="panel3">0</div>
<button class="btn" data-key="panel1">#btn1</button>
<button class="btn" data-key="panel2">#btn2</button>
<button class="btn" data-key="panel3">#btn3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
vars = {
  'x1':0,
  'x2':0,
  'x3':0
}

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var vn = $(this).data('varname');
  var ps = $(this).data('panel-selector');
  vars[vn] += 1;
  $(ps).text(vars[vn]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel3">
  0
</div>
<button class="btn" data-varname='x1' data-panel-selector='#panel1'>#btn1</button>
<button class="btn" data-varname='x2' data-panel-selector='#panel2'>#btn2</button>
<button class="btn" data-varname='x3' data-panel-selector='#panel3'>#btn3</button>
```

**UPD:**
For variables can use eval, but this not secure and useless. **Do not use this, it's just for demonstration.**

```js
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x3 = 0;

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var vn = $(this).data('varname');
  var ps = $(this).data('panel-selector');
  eval(vn + '+=1');
  $(ps).text(eval(vn));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel2">
  0
</div>
<div id="panel3">
  0
</div>
<button class="btn" data-varname='x1' data-panel-selector='#panel1'>#btn1</button>
<button class="btn" data-varname='x2' data-panel-selector='#panel2'>#btn2</button>
<button class="btn" data-varname='x3' data-panel-selector='#panel3'>#btn3</button>
```

Comment: You could use `window[vn]` to avoid `eval()` in your second example.

Comment: Ouch! Please never, never, never bring `eval()` into a conversation that a) wasn't talking about it b) doesn't need it.

Comment: @Mikey Yeah, but Globals should be avoided. Instead, make an object and use the same approach, but with that. See my answer as this is exactly what I show.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I write in comment to snippet is not secure and useless.

Comment: So, why add it to your answer then? Better to remove that part entirely.

Comment: @ScottMarcus because it too variant and have right for exists. I did not force him to use and showed a more correct variant.

Comment: I am of the belief and mindset that there really is never a valid use case for `eval()` beyond applications that need reflection capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that generates the initial variables too, so it should be scalable.

```js
bindVars = {}

$('[data-bind-id]').each(function() {
  var xi = "x" + $(this).data('bind-id');
  var pi = "#panel" + $(this).data('bind-id');
  bindVars[xi] = 0;
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    bindVars[xi] += 1;
    $(pi).text(bindVars[xi]);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1">0</div>
<div id="panel2">0</div>
<div id="panel3">0</div>
<button data-bind-id='1'>#btn1</button>
<button data-bind-id='2'>#btn2</button>
<button data-bind-id='3'>#btn3</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can add every button HTML `onclick` event and create one function.

```js
function add() {
  this.innerHTML(parseInt(this.innerHTML()) + 1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick=add()>1</button>
<button onclick=add()>1</button>
<button onclick=add()>1</button>
```